# disconnecting from Juniper Network Connect VPN on OS X VirtualBox WIndows7 guest fries network

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, juniper

### BACKSTORY:

Every time I disconnect from my Juniper Network Connect VPN (when running the client on the guest), I get a yellow flag on the network icon in the system notification area of my toolbar in Windows7 and the network is unuseable. It's like the Juniper software isn't completely unplumbing the interface it establishes when it initially runs.

I'm running OS X Virtual Box 4.2.18, guest additions 4.2.18r88780, and Win7 Professional service pack 1, and am using NAT.

When I configure multiple interfaces on the guest, each time I run Network Connect and leave it (on the guest) it fouls the interface it was on, so as long as there's an interface left that hasn't been used for Network Connect, I'm good once I leave the VPN.

Virtually disconnecting the cable doesn't restore interface function.
If, however, while the guest is running I change the network from "NAT" to "not attached", save it, then go back in and reverse it, that DOES restore function. I presume that's doing the equivalent of an unplumb.

Rebooting ALWAYS restores function. Specifically, completely shutting down the guest with either a shutdown /s or a poweroff. Doing a shutdown /r to restart but recycle the guest VM does NOT restore function.

### THE QUESTION:

Can someone suggest some VBoxManage, vboxshell.py or other goodness that I could use in a script to boil down my restoration of service steps to just one thing?  I'm thinking I could even periodically ping the outward-facing IP of the guest, and if it goes away when the interface gets fouled, that could be my trigger to run the script.

Thanks!

-KwM-